# Stripping non alphabetic and numeric characters before form submit, using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, input

i have an ajax form
i know i can use like

```
  return str = str.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

to strip stuff before submit
whats the best way to stop form submit when characters that are not alphabetic or numeric are inputed

my the ajax search form is at [vitamovie.com/movies](http://vitamovie.com/movies)

Comment: Whatever you do, this particular stuff really needs to be done in the server side. Simply because JS runs at the client side and can easily be edited/spoofed/modified/hacked by the client. Just let JS submit the form to the server side and (re)do all the validation and sanitization in the server side code.

Comment: i do have stripers in my query file,  
actually, this is sending to wordpress search, and it has all the necessary strip_tags, and other term cleaners
i just do not want to send it to begin with,
because its an ajax search i want to rule out unusable search terms to cut down on server requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When submitting, you can run this on the values:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
  $("input, textarea").each(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, ''));
  });
});
```

Comment: +1, but you should also add a space to the regex: ` /[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g`

Answer (score 0):

\D allows only numbers. \W allows only alpha-numeric